# Django, Multiple requests at the same time

Tags: django, performance, security, ip-address

I have a `middleware.py` file that records IP address on my website.

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

try:
    ip_address = IPAddress.objects.get(ip_address=ip,userprofile=up)
    # Here we can have MultipleObjectsReturned error
    # that's the issue Django emails me about
except IPAddress.DoesNotExist:
    ip_address = IPAddress(ip_address=ip,userprofile=up)
```

Because of something that goes wrong `MultipleObjectsReturned`, Django emails me about bug reports. But I see in all the emails many requests come from different URLs, and oddly at the same time **12:20 PM**

Here are some URLs:

```
my_domain/elastik
my_domain/digium
my_domain/Avaya
my_domain/Zyxel
my_domain/cisco.cfg
my_domain/SIPGateway
...
```

As normal, these URLs don't exist on my website, they suppose to generate 404 error page, but my doubt is why at the same time? why these weird URLs?

Do I need to worry about ? or Does it exist a way to avoid that kind of behavior.

> I host on *DigitalOcean*

Comment: Isn't `ip_address` unique? How could multiple IPAddress objects have the same `ip_address`?

Comment: that's what I thought till I received this weird feedback from django as `MultipleObjectsReturned`

Comment: these multiple URLs are familiar to you?

Comment: You probably have a recycled IP address on DigitalOcean, and the previous owner had set up a scheduled job that does _something_ at 12:20 PM every day that connects to that IP. I suggest you to create a snapshot and move your service to a new droplet to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: thanks @Selcuk I will try. In case the other generated IP have that same issue or scheduled job, I think with it's possible that I find myself in a cycle. Is there another way that can fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. Maybe an NginX/Apache rule that blocks those requests?

Comment: Looks more like a bot scanning your site to see if you might be running a package which has a known vulnerability.

Comment: I know where they come from @Selcuk , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Selcuk I keep in mind what you said about scheduled job from other IP owner.

**A possible solution from @Selcuk**: *I probably have a recycled IP address on DigitalOcean, and the previous owner had set up a scheduled job that does something at 12:20 PM every day that connects to that IP. Create a snapshot and move service to a new droplet*

I spot out what was wrong. **like @GrahamDumpleton said:** *Looks more like a bot scanning your site to see if you might be running a package which has a known vulnerability.* That's right it was a bot scanning, thanks to [`user_agent`](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) package that can be installed with `pip`

```
 >>> request.user_agent.is_bot 
 >>> True
```

I have a table named UserAgent that record everything about each request

```
UserAgent.objects.get_or_create(
    is_mobile = request.user_agent.is_mobile,
    is_tablet = request.user_agent.is_tablet,
    is_touch_capable = request.user_agent.is_touch_capable,
    is_pc = request.user_agent.is_pc,
    is_bot = request.user_agent.is_bot,
    id_address = ip_address,
    is_active = True,
    '''
)
```

**It's not something to worry about in that case**